# In Terraria, what differences are there between stone and wood when used to build a house?

Tags: terraria

Is there any difference between stone and wood when used to build a house?

Apart from the fact that they look different.

Specifically does stone provide more protection?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no difference apart from aesthetics. You can build a house out of anything! Monsters will not spawn unless there is no wall.

Answer (score 1):

Certain materials offer more durability against explosions, which really won't be a problem unless you decide to PVP.

But realistically, your house likely has 1-tile wide walls anyway, so the resistance is almost unnoticeable, and if you ARE building a structure for protection, like a wall to keep monsters out, in most cases a wood wall will do just fine, and be much easier to replace should it get damaged.

You might also get some benefit from a new item: Iron/Lead doors.  Give it a try during a Bloodmoon.

Comment: Well, they changed clowns in hard mode so no worry about them blowing up your home.  Now, stray bombs are still an issue. . . (heh).

Comment: Huh...I must have missed when they removed clowns. I guess then it doesn't make a lot of difference at all anymore, except maybe in PVP.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke.  I believe they still exist; however they can no longer blow up your home.  This was a 1.2 change.

Comment: That makes sense...it would be incredibly frustrating to include a monster who can blow up all your hard work in the game after all...:D

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that after events of blood moon and goblin invasion sometimes some blocks of my house disappeared. My house is made from wooden walls. Maybe material of house make sense, but 100% answer you can get only by reverse ingeneering of game executable.

Comment: Reverse engineering anything in Terraria is against the [TOS](http://www.terraria.org/terms.html)

Comment: It is difficult question. You must check laws of your contry, because them may override TOS in case when TOS and laws say different things. Where I live, dissasembling is legal, but making copies of authorized material and distribution of it is illegal and is prohibited.

Comment: Are you sure that's how it works? I'm asking because it's the first time I've heard that, but I've been known to be wrong before :P

Comment: @Ragnar: IANAL, but common sense says that laws of Sovereign Nations override TOS:s and EULA:s. Then again, common sense cannot always be applied successfully to law. :P

Comment: @Ragnar I guess the main point is what you reverse engineer _for_: Trying to build a shameless clone or stealing game mechanics (evil) or just trying to save you some time (depending on your skills...) on figuring out whether using wood or stone for a house makes a difference (not evil but kind of cheating)

Comment: @WillihamTotland But those same laws *usually* forbid the breaching of license agreements.